# Linq: How to load a second table directly?

Tags: linq

I have 2 tables here:
Auction and Article.

1 Auction has 1 Article.
1 Aricle has x Auctions.

Now I load a list of auctions:

```
            using (APlattformDatabaseDataContext dc = new APlattformDatabaseDataContext())
        {
            List<Auktion> auctionlist = (from a in dc.Auktion
                                         where a.KäuferID == null
                                         select a).ToList();
            return auctionlist;
        }
```

But when I want to "txtBla.Text = auction[0].Article.Text;" it isn't loaded.
The question isn't why (it is logic that it isn't loaded allready and can't be loaded because the DC is closed), but how can I solve this without letting the DC open?

Comment: Are the tables related in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
options.LoadWith<Auktion>(a => a.Article);
dc.LoadOptions = options;
```

Comment: Very easy, tahnks.
Must I do this within every new opened dc?

Comment: Because you are instantiating the context in this way, yes, you'll have to set the DataLoadOptions each time you instantiate the context. you might want to abstract the instantiation to a helper function that includes the DLO so the code exists only in 1 place.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to eager load the associations like that you should use the [DataContext.LoadOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.aspx) property like so...

```
using (APlattformDatabaseDataContext dc = new APlattformDatabaseDataContext())
{
    var dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
    options.LoadWith<Auktion>(o => o.Article);
    dc.LoadOptions = dlo;

    List<Auktion> auctionlist = (from a in dc.Auktion
                                 where a.KäuferID == null
                                 select a).ToList();
    return auctionlist;
}
```

That way your articles will be loaded when your `Auktion` objects are retrieved from the database.